# Store values in sql db as .txt file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, wsdl

I am developing a  simple domain application using web services.I got the domain information using **whois wsdl**.That is working well but I am getting the entire data  the problem is I need only selected data from that server like domain name, creation date,expire date.

In my design I made two text box when entered any domain name in textbox1 if it is exist in whois server it must show selective information into textbox2.

I tried to store these values in a text file and save its name in db but its not working for me. Any ideas friends

Here is my coding

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

 public partial class do01 : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string st = TextBox1.Text;
    wservices.whois myservices = new wservices.whois();
    TextBox2.Text = myservices.GetWhoIS(st);
}
}
```

**Here is my screenshot**

[image: Screen shot]

If you have any ideas just shoot it here friends.... :)

Comment: not a real question -> "Now I need to store that displayed value into database as text file .."

Comment: Do you mean you want all that text in a column in the database?

Comment: No i just want to store the content in a textfile and store that content name in db

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: See update below for a change of answer**

I'm assuming that what you want is to have a table with this information as the plain text in a column.

A basic table definition

```
 CREATE TABLE WhoIsData
 (
     Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
     WhoIsData NVARCHAR(MAX)
 )
```

I don't know what `st` is (which is the data you send to the service, it may be useful in your table if you also want to store that too).

C# code (roughly - I've not tested it)

```
string st = TextBox1.Text;
wservices.whois myservices = new wservices.whois();
string textData = myservices.GetWhoIS(st);
TextBox2.Text = textData;
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString));
{
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO WhoIsData(WhoIsData) VALUES(@text);");
  cmd.Connection = conn;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", textData);
  conn.Open();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I'd separate out the SQL Calls from your user interface classes in real life. But for the sake of the example I've put it all together. Also, I've not renamed your text boxes, although `TextBox1` and `TextBox2` are really bad names.

**UPDATE**

Okay - You want to store the content in a text file, but I'm assuming you want to store a link to the text file in the database (you've not been very specific)

The Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE WhoIsData
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    DomainName NVARCHAR(256),
    WhoIsFile NVARCHAR(256)
)
```

The C# code:

```
string st = TextBox1.Text;
wservices.whois myservices = new wservices.whois();
string textData = myservices.GetWhoIS(st);
TextBox2.Text = textData;

string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
using(var file = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
{
    file.Write(textData);
}

using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString));
{
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO WhoIsData(DomainName, WhoIsFile) VALUES(@domainName, @fileName);");
  cmd.Connection = conn;
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileName", fileName);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@domainName", domainName);
  conn.Open();
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Again, I've not tested this, but it is roughly what you want to do. Also, you need to provide a mechanism for generating the file name, I've just used a guid as it pretty much guarantees uniqueness.